# data.table inner join produces error when no match is found

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am trying to join two data.table using an inner join. It is possible that no matches could be found, then I want an empty data.table with the right col names.

```
dt1 <- data.table(A = c(1,2),  B = c(1,2))
dt2 <- data.table(A = c(3,4),  D = c(3,4))
setkey(dt1, A)
setkey(dt2, A)
dt1[dt2, nomatch = 0]
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
merge(dt1, dt2, 
      all.x = F, 
      all.y = F)

Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,D
```

The second method gives me the desired answer. But I prefer the first syntax because it is faster. Does someone know  how I could solve this error, without using a trycatch statement.

Comment: In recent versions of data.table, you don't need to use `setkey`, so you can reduce this to a single line of code: `dt1[dt2, on="A", nomatch=0]`. Read the section on auto indexing on the [data.table page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error from the first example.. I assume you mean

```
dt1[dt2, nomatch = 0]
```

?

I get:

```
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,D
```

Using latest version of R and data.table

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a typo there:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(A = c(1,2),  B = c(1,2))
dt2 <- data.table(A = c(3,4),  D = c(3,4))

setkey(dt1, A)
setkey(dt2, A)
dt1[dt2, nomatch = 0] #instead of t1[t2, nomatch = 0]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,D
```